# Ruby module namespacing advice

Tags: ruby, namespace

in my current project have:

```
module Stats

  class Site
    ...
  end

  class Product
    def initialize(product_id)
      @product_id = product_id
    end
  end

  class Profile
    ...
  end

end
```

now in my `Product` class have methods to get/set product `views`(day, week, month) and methods to get/set product `sales`(day, week, months)

is better to namespace like `Stats::Product::Views` and `Stats::Product::Sales` or simply prefix methods like `sale_add` and `view_add`?

example calls with namespace:

```
Stats::Product::Sales.add(product_id) # increment sales counter 
Stats::Product::Sales.today(product_id) # get n. today sales  
Stats::Product::Sales.week(product_id) # get n. week sales  

Stats::Product::Views.add(product_id) #increment product page view counter
Stats::Product::Views.today(product_id) #get n. today product page views
Stats::Product::Views.week(product_id) #get n. week product page views
```

example with current structure:

```
Stats::Product(product_id).sale_add # increment sales counter 
Stats::Product(product_id).sales_today  # get n. today sales 
Stats::Product(product_id).sales_week # get n. week sales 

Stats::Product(product_id).view_add #increment product page view counter
Stats::Product(product_id).views_today #get n. today product page views
Stats::Product(product_id).views_week #get n. week product page views
```

Now,  what you think is more elegant solution? and why?

Comment: `sale_add`, `view_add` seems more clarified, anyway what have you to do with `::Views/Sales`?

Comment: "simply prefix methods like sale_add and view_add?".  I don't understand what you mean by this.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Updated question with examples

Comment: The first `Stats::Product::Sales.add(product_id)` variant is more clear.